# How to test Android App behavior when a component is killed by the OS?

Tags: android, android-studio

On android docs I have read that if your app is in background and android os needs to get more resources for another running app it will shutdown or drain the resources of your background app.

I wonder if there are any apps for testing that intentionally just gets as much resources as possible so you can have your app you are developing in background and see when android shuts down its resources anything wrong happens.

Answer (score 5):

To simulate your app getting killed due to system resource limitations, everything you likely need is in the Developer Options on your Android device.

First, I assume you know how to enable [Developer Options](http://www.androidcentral.com/how-enable-developer-settings-android-42).  If not check out the link. It's pretty much the same set of steps for any flavor of Android.

After you have enabled "Developer Options" to show up in the Setting menu on your Android device, select this settings item, scroll down to the bottom and select "Advanced".

Somewhere on that screen is are two settings that you can play with:

- Don't keep activities
- Background process limit

You can play around with both of these options to simulate your app and/or process getting killed when it is not in the foreground.

Note - if you app is running as Service, it automatically runs at a higher privilege than other app's still lingering in the background.  You should check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) on the sort order for how Android selects what apps are considered eligible for termination.

Comment: And I almost forgot - you can always go to the "apps" settings page, select your app and do a "force stop" on it. Ditto for the "recents" button. Swiping an app out of the Recents Apps screen tends to stop its process as well.